# Conditional Update of Column based on partial string match in another column

Tags: python, pandas

**Reproducible Dataframes**

***Table 1***

```
table1 = {'Text':['hello this is', 'a test data', 'frame for', 'stackoverflow'], 'keyid':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
table1 = pd.DataFrame(table1) 

       Text        keyid
0   hello this is   20
1   a test data     21
2   frame for       19
3   stackoverflow   18
```

***Table 2***

```
table2 = {'word': ['hello', 'over','for','is', 'hey'], 'count': [1, 2, 1, 3, 5]}
table2 = pd.DataFrame(table2)

    word    count
0   hello   1
1   over    2
2   for     1
3   is      3
4   hey     5
```

I'm trying to create a conditional update of my table 1 based on the condition: If string in table 2 'word' column is found in table 1 'Text' column, then bring over the 'count' column from table 2, else leave it as NA.

**Expected Output**

```
       Text        keyid   count
0   hello this is   20       1
1   a test data     21       NA
2   frame for       19       1
3   stackoverflow   18       NA
```

> Note: 'over' appears in the Text column but it is not reflected in the expected output, as I do not require matching within the string itself.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 'hello' and 'is' both appear in the first row in table 1, should only 1st match value be updated?

Comment: @anky_91 yes, as long as there is 1 match, be it 'hello' or 'is', return the first matched value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a pattern by word boundaries and then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to get the respective table2 `count`:

```
d=table2.set_index('word')['count']
p='({})'.format('\\b|\\b'.join(table2.word))
#'(hello\\b|\\bover\\b|\\bfor\\b|\\bis\\b|\\bhey)'
table1['count']=table1.Text.str.extract(p,expand=False).map(d)
print(table1)
```

---

```
            Text  keyid  count
0  hello this is     20    1.0
1    a test data     21    NaN
2      frame for     19    1.0
3  stackoverflow     18    NaN
```

Comment: @Javier yw. :) happy coding.